# Calculate average with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to print an average with xslt and having a hard time trying to figure out a way.
I have answers in a separate node and questions in a separate node. Need to match the question id with answer and calculate average

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
 <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl"?>
   <details>
     <detail>
      <answersall>
        <answers>
          <question id="1"/>
          <answer>4</answer>
          <note>test</note>
      </answers>
      <answers>
        <question id="2"/>
        <answer>2</answer>
      </answers>
      <answers>
        <question id="3"/>
        <answer>2</answer>
      </answers>
      <answers>
        <question id="4"/>
        <answer>3</answer>
      </answers>
    </answerall>
  </detail>
  <questions>
   <question id="1" text="Hello how are you" section="a"/>
   <question id="2" text="how was your day" section="a"/>
   <question id="3" text="it was good" section="b"/>
   <question id="4" text="take care" section="b"/>
  </questions>
</details>
```

I am trying to print something like this
`Question              Answer`
`Section A                3 (average)`
`1. Hello how are you     4`
`2.How was your day       2`
`Section B               2.5`
`3. It was good           2`
`4. Take Care             3`

I have got the part to print the questions and answers but not the average. I know i cannot use a variable inside a for loop.

Below is my xslt.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
   <html>
     <body>
      <h2><center>Details</center></h2>
       <table>
         <tr>
           <td>Section A</td>
           <td>????</td>
         </tr>
         <xsl:for-each select="details/questions/question[@section='a']">
           <xsl:variable name="id" select="@id"/>
             <tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="@text"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="//answers[question/@id=$id]/answer"/></td>
             </tr>
         </xsl:for-each>
     </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Basically, this is a *grouping* question. See http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html and numerous examples here on SO. -- Note also: your XML is not well-formed, and the XSLT you show us uses an undefined variable.

Comment: I look at this example. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222647/get-the-average-of-elements-values-in-xsl. But i am not able to figure out how to point to picks question based on the section and go find the average in a seperate node

Comment: Will there always be exactly two sections, `a` and `b`?

Comment: There are actually 5. For simplicity i added 2.

Comment: Yes, but are they *constant*?  IOW, would be alright to hard-code them into the stylesheet?

Comment: They are constants. For now they will remain hardcoded and i will later add them to xml and derive from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's something you could use as your starting point:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="question-by-section" match="question" use="@section" />
<xsl:key name="answer-by-question" match="answers" use="question/@id" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Question</th>
            <th>Answer</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:call-template name="generate-section">     
            <xsl:with-param name="section">a</xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:call-template name="generate-section">     
            <xsl:with-param name="section">b</xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
     </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="generate-section">
    <xsl:param name="section"/>
    <xsl:variable name="questions" select="key('question-by-section', $section)" />
    <xsl:variable name="answers" select="key('answer-by-question', $questions/@id)" />
    <tr>
        <th>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('Section ', $section)" />
        </th>
        <th>
            <xsl:value-of select="sum($answers/answer) div count($answers)" />          
        </th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="$questions">
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="@text"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="key('answer-by-question', @id)/answer"/></td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input (after correcting the `answersall` vs `answerall` mismatch!), the result will look like this:

[image]

I would urge you strongly to adopt [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) to select distinct sections, instead of the hard-coded repeated call to a named template shown here.

Comment: @Daniel Haley You are welcome to copy the averaging mechanism from here.

Comment: I appreciate that, but I'll leave my answer deleted. +1 for a great answer (as per usual).

Comment: This worked. I would definitely change the hardcoded value for section and put in a for loop to read from xml. Thanks!