# Shell script to parse JTL files of last 10 runs

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, jmeter

I have a sample jtl file as shown below:
I have to read time taken for each operation as highlighted by JR_*, time is in t="" from the latest 10 jtl files, and compute the average value.
I am trying to do a shell script which will do this specific action of computing average of a particular operation for the last 10 runs, (read latest 10 jtl files)

```
<sample t="5203" it="0" lt="0" ts="1493818151051" s="true" lb="JR_READ" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="Thread Group 1-2" dt="text" by="0" ng="2" na="2"/>
<sample t="3584" it="0" lt="0" ts="1493818151660" s="true" lb="JR_WRITE" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="Thread Group 1-2" dt="text" by="0" ng="2" na="2"/>
<sample t="61280" it="0" lt="0" ts="1493818152265" s="true" lb="JR_SAVE" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="Thread Group 1-2" dt="text" by="0" ng="2" na="2"/>
<sample t="129935" it="0" lt="0" ts="1493818152870" s="true" lb="JR_DELETE" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="Thread Group 1-2" dt="text" by="0" ng="2" na="2"/>
```

I'm trying some thing like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /tests/unit/
fNames=$(ls -t | grep -i jenkins-TEST_UNIT | head -n 10)
#printf "%s\n" "${fNames[@]}"
## now loop through the above array
for i in "${fNames[@]}"
do
   #echo "$i"
  grep -I "JR_READ" $i/Summary.jtl | awk -F '"' '{print $2}'
   # or do whatever with individual element of the array
done
```

I get the "time" as needed for only one file, rest of the directories I get this error, what could be the reason? grep works fine ONLY for ONE file.

```
grep: jenkins-TEST_UNIT12: Is a directory
grep: jenkins-TEST_UNIT9: Is a directory
grep: jenkins-TEST_UNIT8: Is a directory
grep: jenkins-TEST_UNIT7: Is a directory
grep: jenkins-TEST_UNIT6: Is a directory
grep: jenkins-TEST_UNIT5: Is a directory
grep: jenkins-TEST_UNIT4: Is a directory
grep: jenkins-TEST_UNIT3: Is a directory
grep: jenkins-TEST_UNIT2: Is a directory
60665
```

ideas welcome, 
thanks

Comment: that output you have posted, is it a single jtl file contents? Can you give more details?

Comment: What did you try for yourself

Comment: awk is a good tool for this kind of shell operation. Use `t=$2;gsub(/^[^"]*"|"$/, "";t)` for getting the time on each line (similar for operation with field $7)

Comment: please check above, I have updated with my experiment

Answer (score 0):

There are several better options:

1. Feed your .jtl result files to [JChav](http://jchav.blogspot.com/)
2. Run your JMeter tests via [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/), [Jenkins Performance Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Performance+Plugin) has "Performance Trend" chart configurable to display various metrics including response time
3. Upload your result files to [BM.Sense](https://sense.blazemeter.com/) service which has different test runs comparison feature

If none of the options plays for you it is better to consider [computing the average via XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222647/get-the-average-of-elements-values-in-xsl)